# Confusion about the difference between declarations and definitions in C++

Tags: c++

I am confused. In part 3.8 of Bjarne Stroustrup's book 'Programming Principles and Practice Using C++' he talks about types of objects. I cite the following list:

> - A *type* defines a set of possible values and a set of operations (for an object).
> - An *object* is some memory that holds a value of a given type.
> - A *value* is a set of bits in memory interpreted according to a type.
> - A *variable* is a named object.
> - A *declaration* is a statement that gives a name to an object.
> - A *definition* is a declaration that sets aside memory for an object.

From his explanation of *definition* I understand that no memory is set aside for an object during *declaration*. However, the fact that Bjarne mentions that *declaration* involves the naming of an object, suggests that memory is actually set aside, as *objects* are explained as being

> some memory that holds a value of a given type.

Can someone clarify this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration)

Answer (score 2):

One of the complexities of C++ is that compilation is done in "translation units" (without seeing the whole program). Each translation units contains declarations of some parts defined in other translation units and definitions of some other parts. The declaration provides enough information to be able to generate code that **uses** the declared part once the address will be resolved by the linker.

Only one definition for an object or non-inline function is allowed in a program but there can be multiple declarations.

Things are indeed even more complex than this because of templates and some magic that C++ can do at link time (e.g. static variables in inline functions).

A declarations says "there is an object/function like this somewhere", a definition says "make an object/function like this".